# Give an example of a space $X$, a subset $A$ and topology on $A$ such that $i: A \rightarrow X$ is NOT continuous

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I was thinking of taking $X=\{0,1,2\}$ and $A=\{1,2\}$

And then the primage of ${0}$ is empty?

I do not know which topology to take

Thanks

Comment: Just so you know. Saying the preimage of $0$ is empty is not helpful as any topology has the empty set as an open-closed set by definition. For your example maybe you can try the topology on $X$ to be $\{\emptyset , X , \{1\}\}$ and on $A$ to be $\{\emptyset , A , \{2\}\}$. Then $i^{-1}(1)=1$ is not open in $A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $X=\mathbb R$ with usual topology and $A=\mathbb Z$ with indiscrete topology. (The one in which only empty set and whole set are open). This is not continuous as the inverse image $i^{-1}(n-\epsilon,n+\epsilon)=\{n\}$ for any $n\in \mathbb Z$ and for some $0<\epsilon <1$ is not open in $\mathbb Z$ and hence $i$ is not continuous.

Answer (score 2):

Take any set $X$ such that $|X|>1$ and any $A\subset X$ such that $|A|>1$.

Let $T_X$ be the discrete topology on $X$: $T_X = \{U|U\subset X\}$.

Let $T_A$ be the indiscrete topology on $A$: $T_A = \{\varnothing, A\}$.

Let $f:A\rightarrow X$ be the inclusion of $A$ into $X$.

Now, take any element $a\in A$. Since $f^{-1}(\{a\})=\{a\}$, $\{a\}\in T_X$ and $\{a\} \not\in T_A$, $f$ is not continuous.